# Angular 5 - HTTP post

Tags: http, angular5

I have a backend interface which I invoke with my Angular 1.3 application without problems. With my Angular 5 application I get an HTTP 403 (Forbidden)
I faced the request parameters in an picture (Angular 1.3 at the left side, Angular 5 at the right side):

[image: Angular5 vs Angular1.3]

My Angular 5 code looks like this:

```
createDate(calendarEvent: CalendarEvent) {
    let serialDates = false;
    let calendarEventSerialDateType = 'NO_SERIAL_DATE';
    let serialEndDate = this.utilService.convertDateToDateString(new Date());
    let url: string = environment.apiEndpoint + 'calendarevents/calendarevent/' + serialDates + '/' + calendarEventSerialDateType + '/' + serialEndDate + '/';
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': this.authService.getToken()});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(url, calendarEvent, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

}

I have e.g. no idea why **X-AUTH-TOKEN** is not set with Angular 5 because I set it in the headers object with

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': this.authService.getToken()});
```

and why **OPTIONS** is mentioned at Request Method with Angular 5 instead of **POST** like with angular 1.3.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTIONS** request is considered as a pre-flight request, which is sent before the actual request to check the existence of method.

If the request sent is a valid one, it will call the valid method.

And regarding the request header, you can use the one in the above answer.

```
 let Options = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let Options = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};
```

return this.http.post(url, calendarEvent, Options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => console.log(res));

Comment: @quma otherwise, create a service=> creating a file name as,<filename>.service.ts - Inside that perform your API call                          =>if you want to know more let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular5,

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-AUTH-TOKEN', this.authService.getToken());
```

1. By default, `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`
2. Stop using `map`.
3. Subscribe the response and store it to Observable for further access.

***Example:***

```
createDate(calendarEvent: CalendarEvent) {
  let serialDates = false;
  let calendarEventSerialDateType = 'NO_SERIAL_DATE';
  let serialEndDate = this.utilService.convertDateToDateString(new Date());
  let url: string = environment.apiEndpoint + 'calendarevents/calendarevent/' + serialDates + '/' + calendarEventSerialDateType + '/' + serialEndDate + '/';
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-AUTH-TOKEN', this.authService.getToken());
  return this.http.post(url, calendarEvent, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => console.log(res)); 
}
```